# Connecting List with Document Library

Tags: document-library, custom-list, content-editor-web-part

I am trying to create a list which is connected to a Document Library.

Actually I want to create a list and when I add a new item, have the option not only to create the item, but also to add documents to this item.

So when I open this item I have directly connected and can visualize the documents I uploaded in the moment I created the item . What is really important in order to work with workflow processes.

The idea is to do all the process in the same "add-item" site, so the users don't have to move to the Document Library to connect the documents or work with lookup fields themselves.

(Edit)  The wish is to have this document library under the list fields and the idea is avoid to use the "Attach Files". Actually is the main work of this, although I still don't understand why they want it this way.

I can use CEWP and Code in, but no probability to install SharePoint Designer or an IDE, So I will code it in Notepad++!

Comment: have you tried add documents as attachement on list

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to connect with document library.You can also upload attachment in list item in SharePoint list.There is option available "**Attach file**" in ribbon for upload documents.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick answer. I forgot to add that the wish is to have this document Library under the List Fields and the idea is avoid to use the "Attach Files". Actually is the main work of this, although I still don´t understand why they want it this way :-(

Comment: I think,OOTB there is no option available for same.

Comment: Hi! Is not a OOTB solution, Actually I can code, I just edited the post in order to explain myself better.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the document library itself ?

In the document library, you can create the columns that you need and the ones that you created in the list, make them in the doc lib. They will show up in the popup after document is uploaded where user has the option to fill this metadata and other lookup values that you want , see below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Because I need to have more than one documents related in a only one Element (In this case I am using a List element), so all of them can go through a only one Workflow process.

Comment: Hello ! Ok I see now :) then the best option would be to develop a custom form with multiple file upload option